# How to use JavaRX to update UI when using ROOM

Tags: java, android, reactivex

I have 1 Room DAO file named `DatabaseDAO` and 2 Activities named `ViewTasks` and `AddTask`. (In `ViewTasks` I have a list of tasks from my database and in `AddTask` I can add a new task).

I launch `AddTask` from `ViewTasks`

In my `ViewTasks`, in `onCreate` method I tried to:

```
disposable.add(
        databaseDAO.create()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // read DB in background
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())  // show results in mainThread
        .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<long[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(long[] longs) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User created!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // To be replaced with DB interrogation
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error during the creating user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // To be replaced with error message
            }
        }));
```

*NOTE: disposable is an instance of `CompositeDisposable`, initialized in `onCreated` and cleaned in `onDestroy`*

So every time somewhere `DatabaseDAO.create(User...)` would be called, and the observer would still exist, the UI will update

`DatabaseDAO`

```
@Dao
public interface DatabaseDAO {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    public long[] create(User... users);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM 
    public Single<User[]> getAllUsers();
}
```

How do I use JavaRX in Android to update my list in `ViewTasks` after I add an task in `AddTask`?
If I try to wrap `public long[] create(User... users);` around `Single<T>` 
I get the following error:

`Error:(31, 27) error: Methods annotated with @Insert can return either void, long, Long, long[], Long[] or List<Long>.`

EDIT1: my `gradle` file is:

```
dependencies {

/* Room dependencies */
/* You need to add those so Android will add Room to your project */
/* After that you can use all the annotations Room provide */
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"


compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'

implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.0.0-alpha5'
```

}

*NOTE: it's my very first time using JavaRX and critics are welcomed*

Comment: have u tried wrapping to Completable?

Comment: I have used something like this   Override
    public Completable insertGeneralNotification(final GeneralNotificationModel notification) {
        return Completable.fromCallable(new Callable<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                return pushNotificationDataBase.storeGeneralNotification(notification);
            }
        });
    }

Comment: Did you put RxJava support for Room persistense inside your gradle file; like discribed in this [article](https://medium.com/google-developers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757). In that case you will be able to wrap _long[]_ inside Single or Flowable.

Comment: @maheryhaja Yes, I've updated my question